# Asterisk and underscore behave differently with markdown in chat and comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, markdown

From the formatting help ([on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#italics-bold) and [on the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting)), it seems like `*` and `_` should be interchangeable (in pairs) wrt emphasis (bold and italic).

However, as [this (correct)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/18397493/history) and [this (incorrect)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/18397438/history) link show, backticks stop working when using underscores for emphasis.

Can haz fix?

Answer (score 3):

This should be fixed next time we deploy chat

Comment: Thanks. What about comments? They exhibit the same problem, although maybe I should've been more clear about that.